# ubuntu reboot & shutdown command with password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, shutdown, reboot

I am writing a program in Java to shut-down the Ubuntu server.

```
 echo password | sudo -S shutdown -h now
 sudo -p 'password' shutdown -h now
```

either of the commands didn't work.

I need sudo command for shut-down and reboot my server by passing password.
since I am doing this from program it should not prompt for password. the password should also be sent with the command. any suggestions will be helpful.....

Answer (score 1):

The -p  option of sudo specifies a prompt , not a password. Take a look at the -A option. An extract from the sudo man page-:

```
 -A          Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the current 
             terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a
             helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the 
             password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable 
             is set, it specifies the path to the helper program.  Otherwise, the value
             specified by the askpass  option in sudoers(5) is used.
```

The helper program must output the correct password. So to specify the helper program-:

```
 export SUDO_ASKPASS="/path/to/helper"
```